# Flyway checksum mismatch after restore of database

Tags: flyway

I've restores a backup of my database from another environment into a test/development environment, but when starting the application up I get a checksum mismatch error

> Sep 10, 2019 3:50:50 PM org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate validate
>   INFO: Validated 146 migrations (execution time 00:00.193s)
>   Exception in thread "main" org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed. Migration Checksum mismatch for migration 2.20170627213900

I'm currently using an old version of flyway (3.2.1) (plan to upgrade in the near future but can't right now) and can't find docs for this version - so I'm not sure if any of the properties listed on the website are even valid.

What is the normal/recommended process for handling the restore between environments? I'm assuming the reason for failure is that the checksum for the migration file is being calculated on the 'dev' environment filesystem and then being compared to the checksum in the schema_version database table which was previously calculated as the checksum for the file on the other environment?

Comment: This type of error happens when there has been edit to one or more of the SQL migration files which have already been applied through flyway. Can you check the version history behind: 2.20170627213900?